# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.python.keras.api._v2.keras.activations' has no attribute 'swish'

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using Azure ML studio to train a question answering ALBERT model with the SQuAD dataset. I'm getting the following error. Here is the code I execute.

```py
# Clone transformers github repo
!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/transformers \
&& cd transformers \
&& git checkout a3085020ed0d81d4903c50967687192e3101e770 

# Install libraries
# !pip install ./transformers
!pip install transformers
!pip install tensorboardX

# Get data
! mkdir dataset \
&& cd dataset \
&& wget https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/train-v2.0.json \
&& wget https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/dataset/dev-v2.0.json

# Train model
!export SQUAD_DIR=/content/dataset \
&& python transformers/examples/run_squad.py \
    --model_type albert \
    --model_name_or_path albert-base-v2 \
    --do_train \
    --do_eval \
    --do_lower_case \
    --train_file $SQUAD_DIR/train-v2.0.json \
    --predict_file $SQUAD_DIR/dev-v2.0.json \
    --per_gpu_train_batch_size 12 \
    --learning_rate 3e-5 \
    --num_train_epochs 1.0 \
    --max_seq_length 384 \
    --doc_stride 128 \
    --output_dir /content/model_output \
    --save_steps 1000 \
    --threads 4 \
    --version_2_with_negative
```

I'm using an NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPU. When I execute the cell above to train the model, I get the following error:

```py
2020-10-31 01:31:45.732913: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-10-31 01:31:45.733023: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-10-31 01:31:45.733043: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "transformers/examples/run_squad.py", line 32, in <module>
    from transformers import (
    File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    from .pipelines import (
    File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/pipelines.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .modeling_tf_auto import (
    File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_auto.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .modeling_tf_albert import (
    File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/modeling_tf_albert.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .activations_tf import get_tf_activation
    File "/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/transformers/activations_tf.py", line 53, in <module>
    "swish": tf.keras.activations.swish,
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_core.python.keras.api._v2.keras.activations' has no attribute 'swish'
```

Answer (score 10):

Solved

Needed to add:

```
!pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu # for Python 3.n and GPU
```

Comment: So slow.... 3 minutes and still running (though this is a kinda slow box)